# Flipping and annotating image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have `flipIt()` function to flip image. but what I want to do is when user clicks on image a dynamic div (background and some Text) must be created and then that div must be visible on when image is flipped.

This fiddle is not working please help.
http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/13/

```
$("img").click(function(){
    alert('m called');
    $(this).wrap('<div class="foobar"/>');

    $(this).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(this).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(this).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(this).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");

    $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    $(this).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
});
```

Comment: you have an extra '.' with in the code inside jsfiddle " flipIt( $(this).);" errors corrected http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/15/

Comment: add jquery from sidebar .

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ62f/20/)?

Comment: but image is not Flipping .. flipit() not working here

Comment: I hope my answer has helped you, you can phrase exact problem here

Comment: no when image is flip only div should be visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p9KqQ/2/)

```
$("img").click(function()
{
    var _this = $(this);
    _this.wrap('<div class="foobar"/>');
    _this.css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    _this.css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    _this.css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    _this.css("transition","all 1.0s linear");
    _this.css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    _this.css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
});
```

Or you can do something like this

```
function _flipIt(image , div)
{
    var _this = image;
    _this.wrap(div);
    _this.css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    _this.css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    _this.css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    _this.css("transition","all 1.0s linear");
    _this.css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    _this.css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
}

$("img").click(function()
{
    _flipIt($(this) , '<div class="foobar"/>');
    // hide image
    $(this).css('visibility' , 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by only div? use _this.css('visibility' , 'hidden');

Comment: when i am printing                                               alert('classes ..'+$(this).hasClass("foobar").toString());                  to check if classes has been added to div or not its showing false???

Comment: This would be $(this).parent().hasClass("foobar")); as you have appended image to a div and $(this) represent image

Comment: i want to check if images has been added to div or not

Comment: if( $('.foobar').find('img').length >0 )

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of errors there. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/EhUp2/3/

I prefer to add a class then lots of css trough JS.

markup:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="card">
  <div class="front face">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/450x280"/>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 280px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.back.face {
 display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
$('#container').click(function(){

    $(this).children('#card').append("<div class='back face'><p>Text.</p></div>").addClass('flip');   

});
```

Comment: my Question was how to add images in div dynamically... this code i have tried http://jsfiddle.net/YaUPs/ , i cant add div in html directly thats why i want tryng  to created and add to div dynamically

Comment: No... i want only img tags on HTML there should not be any div .